# How do you assign a single number to both unique and duplicate values (IN EXCEL)?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find out how to assign a number to both unique and duplicate values.

For example, Joe is listed THREE times, Roy is listed ONCE, Tom is listed ONCE, Bob is listed TWICE, and Lee is listed ONCE.

Is there a way to assign a 2 to all duplicate names (being Joe and Bob) and a 1 to all original names (being Roy, Tom and Lee)?

**Preferably without highlighting or sorting if possible**

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the data?

Comment: No, it's already in a Fliter Table, which I think prevents sorting.

Comment: What do you mean by 'assign to'? Do you mean, put the value in the cell next to the name?

Comment: Yes, so for example, Joe would be in A1, and B1 should have a 2, and Roy would be in A2 and in B2 there should be a 1...etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IF` around a `COUNTIF` for this. E.g. If my first name is in A2, then in cell B2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$9,A2)>1,2,1)
```

Example:

[image: countif]

Comment: I only want to use two numbers, 1 for unique numbers and 2 for duplicates. I think this may need a conditional format formula but I'm not sure.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to mention the range , you can run it for entire column just by mentioning -IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,2,1)